# Firebase Cloud Messaging returns 200 OK for token that has unsubscribed

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We use the Firebase Java SDK (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin) to send Push Notifications to iOS and Android devices.

We can successfully construct a notification, and send it to a device using the registered FCM token.

On such a device, we opened System Settings, and disabled push notification for the application.
We sent a new notification using FCM, and it did not appear on the device - as expected.
However, we now expect that the Firebase API should throw an Exception, because the FCM token is no longer valid / has been revoked.

We figured it may be cached for a while, but it has now been over 24 hours. We need to be able to fallback to other delivery methods if push has been disabled on a device.
Why does FCM still return 200 OK?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling notifications for the application does not automatically unregister that application with Firebase Cloud Messaging. If you re-enable notifications to that application, the OS will happily deliver notifications again, and it will (as far as I know) continue to use the same token.

Comment: I have now deleted the application fully, which should invalidate the token, but FCM still accepts the message and attempts to deliver it. It's been over 24 hours as well

Comment: I have still not found an answer to this issue. If a user disables Push Notifications or deletes the application we need to be able to fallback to other methods for notifying them.. How should we do that?

Comment: If the user indicates they don't want to receive notifications from your app, Android will honor that request. If the user uninstalls the app, there's definitely no way left for it to display notifications. Both of these are by design, and intentional. There's no workaround beyond using a completely separate system to notify them, such as email or SMS. But think carefully before you do this, as there's a reason the user chose to disable notifications from your app, and/or to uninstall it.